# PHP - select limited csv rows

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and am trying to display some contents from CSV in a webpage. I am able to display the values successfully. I need to find the minimum and maximum of all the columns so that I can include a slider using which the user can select a range. This is the code I have to find the minimum and maximum values for all the columns.

```
$total_columns = 0;
$handle1 = fopen('demo.csv', 'r');
while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($handle1, 1000, ','))) {
    0 === $total_columns and $total_columns = count($row);
    $i = 1;
    while (++$i <= $total_columns) {
         $data1[$i][] = (int) $row[$i - 1];
     }
}

$i = 0;
while (++$i <= $total_columns) {
    $_SESSION["min-column-$i"] = min($data1[$i]);
    $_SESSION["max-column-$i"] = max($data1[$i]);
}
```

Using the above code, I have implemented a slider functionality for range selection.. After this range selection, I need to display only those rows that satisfy the range. For example,

- a1 1 2 3
- a2 3 4 5
- a3 8 9 10

If I have a slider for column 1(min is 1 and max is 8) and if I choose the range value as 8, I need to display only the a3 row. My output should be,

- a3 8 9 10

Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: Don't know if this would help, but: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that PHP is all server side code so you'll have a few options here.

1. Process your data and create a div for each row hiding all of them. Store the ranges in javascript and write a method to check the user value against those ranges and hide/show the respective row.
2. On select of the range value, make an ajax call to a PHP script that would determine the row and return it. You'd then display it in a single results div.
3. Take a similar approach as #2, but post the data back to a script that did the same thing and displayed the results.

I'd look into #1 since you have to process all of the CSV data to determine ranges anyway. #2 and #3 both require you to reprocess the data a 2nd time to get the results.